# Testing windows 8 application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Can we test windows 8 mobile app windows phone 8 simulator.I need to test my windows 8 mobile application.but simulator in visual studio 2012 is only for tablets,there is no simulator form mobile device

Comment: What do you have and what do you want to test?

Comment: I think you don't have windows phone sdk installed on your system

Comment: right..I hadnt. and one more mistake I have done,I used windows 8 platform instead of windows phone 8.Now all issues are solved..thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think You need to install windows phone 8 sdk to your machine. It include all the emulators to test windows phone app.

Answer (score 1):

Like Praveen said it seems like you don't have the SDK installed. To download it simply go to this address http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk and download the latest SDK. you will need to have VS closed when installing and may require a restart. Ohh and just incase you don't you will need windows 8 Pro to test using the emulator as it requires HyperV.